# Pasar elementos de una lista a ser keys de otros elementos de un diccionario en Python

Tags: python, lista, diccionarios

Tengo una data en la cual tengo un diccionario con listas anidadas, mis datos se encuentran de la siguiente forma:

```
data = {
   'Articulos': [
     {
      'id': 1, 
      'titulo': 'Titulo 1', 
      'keywords': 'keywords1', 
      'descripcion': 'asdsadsadsasdadsa', 
      'nombre_proyecto': 'Diferentes dentro del del Conocimiento Tradicional del Pueblo Saraguro', 
      'link_articulo': 'https://linkarticulo1', 
      'mapeo': 
           [
            'Id', 
            'Titulo', 
            'Keywords', 
            'Descripcion', 
            'Nombre Proyecto', 
            'Link Articulo'
           ]
      }, 
      {
       'id': 3, 
       'titulo': 'Titulo 2', 
       'keywords': 'keywords2', 
       'descripcion': 'El cancerpor esta enfermeda', 
       'nombre_proyecto': 'PROSPECCION DE', 
       'link_articulo': 'https://linkarticulo2', 
       'mapeo': 
            [
               'Id', 
               'Titulo', 
               'Keywords', 
               'Descripcion', 
               'Nombre Proyecto', 
               'Link Articulo'
             ]
      }
    ] 
   'Proyectos': [
      {
       'codigo_proyecto': 'Proy_001', 
       'mapeo': 
            [
             'Codigo Proyecto'
            ]
       }, 
       {
        'codigo_proyecto': 'PROY_CBCM_0011', 
        'mapeo': 
             [
              'Codigo Proyecto'
             ]
       }
    ]
}
```

El problema que tengo es que no puedo pasar los valores que se encuentran en `mapeo` a los valores que se encuentran sobre `mapeo`. Necesito que los valores que se encuentran en `mapeo` pasen a ser como claves de los valores que se encuentran por ejemplo en `Articulos` y obtener algo así:

```
Id: 1
Titulo: Titulo 1
Keywords: keywords1 
Descripcion: asdsadsadsasdadsa 
Nombre Proyecto: Diferentes dentro del del Conocimiento Tradicional del Pueblo Saraguro 
Link Articulo: https://linkarticulo1

Id: 3
Titulo: Titulo 2
Keywords: keywords2
Descripcion: El cancerpor esta enfermeda
Nombre Proyecto: PROSPECCION DE
Link Articulo: https://linkarticulo2
```

Lo mismo con `Proyectos` para obtener lo siguiente:

```
Codigo Proyecto: Proy_001
Codigo Proyecto: PROY_CBCM_0011
```

La verdad no se como hacerlo. Espero se me haya entendido y me puedan ayudar a solucionar esto. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función zip() te puede ayudar

```
def uso_de_zip():
    data = {
       'Articulos': [
         {
          'id': 1,
          'titulo': 'Titulo 1',
          'keywords': 'keywords1',
          'descripcion': 'asdsadsadsasdadsa',
          'nombre_proyecto': 'Diferentes dentro del del Conocimiento Tradicional del Pueblo Saraguro',
          'link_articulo': 'https://linkarticulo1',
          'mapeo':
               [
                'Id',
                'Titulo',
                'Keywords',
                'Descripcion',
                'Nombre Proyecto',
                'Link Articulo'
               ]
          },
          {
           'id': 3,
           'titulo': 'Titulo 2',
           'keywords': 'keywords2',
           'descripcion': 'El cancerpor esta enfermeda',
           'nombre_proyecto': 'PROSPECCION DE',
           'link_articulo': 'https://linkarticulo2',
           'mapeo':
                [
                   'Id',
                   'Titulo',
                   'Keywords',
                   'Descripcion',
                   'Nombre Proyecto',
                   'Link Articulo'
                 ]
          }
        ],
       'Proyectos': [
          {
           'codigo_proyecto': 'Proy_001',
           'mapeo':
                [
                 'Codigo Proyecto'
                ]
           },
           {
            'codigo_proyecto': 'PROY_CBCM_0011',
            'mapeo':
                 [
                  'Codigo Proyecto'
                 ]
           }
        ]
    }

    for articulo in data['Articulos']:
        resultados = dict(zip(articulo['mapeo'], articulo.values()))
        for clave in resultados.keys():
            print('{}: {}'.format(clave, resultados[clave]))
        print()

    for proyecto in data['Proyectos']:
        resultados = dict(zip(proyecto['mapeo'], proyecto.values()))
        for clave in resultados.keys():
            print('{}: {}'.format(clave, resultados[clave]))
```

Que da como resultado...

```
Id: 1
Titulo: Titulo 1
Keywords: keywords1
Descripcion: asdsadsadsasdadsa
Nombre Proyecto: Diferentes dentro del del Conocimiento Tradicional del Pueblo Saraguro
Link Articulo: https://linkarticulo1

Id: 3
Titulo: Titulo 2
Keywords: keywords2
Descripcion: El cancerpor esta enfermeda
Nombre Proyecto: PROSPECCION DE
Link Articulo: https://linkarticulo2

Codigo Proyecto: Proy_001
Codigo Proyecto: PROY_CBCM_0011
```

Encontrarás más ejemplos aquí: https://ellibrodepython.com/zip-python

Answer (score 2):

Ofrezco esta solución:

```
def crear_dicts(diccionarios):
    """
    Recibe una lista de diccionarios y retorna otra lista
    con nuevas llaves.

    :param diccionarios: lista de diccionarios.
    :return: otra lista de diccionarios.
    """
    nuevo = []
    for ele in diccionarios:
        elemento = {}
        for par in zip(ele.keys(), ele['mapeo']):
            elemento[par[1]] = ele[par[0]]
        nuevo.append(elemento)
    return nuevo
```

Esta función recibe una lista de diccionarios. Cada elemento de la lista tiene una llave `mapeo` cuyo valor es una lista de nombres. Con cada elemento, debe crearse uno nuevo, usando como llaves los nombres de la lista de `mapeo`. Los elementos se hacen corresponder uno a uno.

La función itera sobre los elementos del diccionario con un `for`. Esto nos da cada elemento. Usando `keys()` extraemos la lista de llaves del diccionario y con `zip` hace una secuencia de pares ordenados con la lista de `mapeo`.

Con esta información ya podemos crear el nuevo diccionario: tenemos la nueva llave y el antiguo valor.

**Demo**

```
from pprint import pprint

pprint(crear_dicts(data['Articulos']))
pprint(crear_dicts(data['Proyectos']))
```

produce:

```
[{'Descripcion': 'asdsadsadsasdadsa',
  'Id': 1,
  'Keywords': 'keywords1',
  'Link Articulo': 'https://linkarticulo1',
  'Nombre Proyecto': 'Diferentes dentro del del Conocimiento Tradicional del '
                     'Pueblo Saraguro',
  'Titulo': 'Titulo 1'},
 {'Descripcion': 'El cancerpor esta enfermeda',
  'Id': 3,
  'Keywords': 'keywords2',
  'Link Articulo': 'https://linkarticulo2',
  'Nombre Proyecto': 'PROSPECCION DE',
  'Titulo': 'Titulo 2'}]
[{'Codigo Proyecto': 'Proy_001'}, {'Codigo Proyecto': 'PROY_CBCM_0011'}]
```